# Um template mas que não pode ser const

Tags: c++, funções, template

Eu tenho uma função template, ela leva dois ou mais parâmetros, mas um deles não pode ser `const` , como nesse exemplo:

```c
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void TesteFunc(T1* Matriz1, T2* Matriz2, ...) // Outros argumentos que para essa pergunta não importa
{
    Matriz1[0] = 0;  // Modifica os valores
    // Outras coisas
}
```

Nesse caso, o segundo argumento até pode ser constante, mas o primeiro **não pode**, já que eu preciso os modificar os seus valores. É possível eu forçar o primeiro argumento a não ser constante? Caso não seja, eu posso no máximo comentar na função que aquele argumento não aceita `const` , mas caso haja uma maneira, seria muito melhor.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta, veja o exemplo https://ideone.com/DcHLGa

Comment: @AugustoVasques Agora eu vi que ao compilar dá um erro, mas o problema era que uma pessoa podia sem saber,  passar um valor constante mesmo não podendo. Mas agora eu vi que ao compilar isso dá um erro.

Comment: Para passar uma constante seria assim https://ideone.com/UhvfLP mas a constante não pode ser alterada lançando o erro `error: assignment of read-only location ‘* Matriz1’`

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu sei como passar parâmetros `const`, o que eu pensava é que o compilador iria aceitar e compilar a função mesmo assim e depois crasharia o programa durante o uso.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como é um template a IDE não mostra isso como um erro:

```c
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void TesteFunc(T1* Matriz1, T2* Matriz2, ...)
{
    Matriz1[0] = 0;
    // Outras coisas
}

const char* teste = "Ola";

char MatTeste[] = { 0 };

int main()
{
    TesteFunc(teste, MatTeste, ...);
}
```

Mas ao compilar  isso gera um erro, pois não é possível modificar os valores em Matriz1, assim o usuários são forçados a usar variáveis não constantes.

Comment: Eu fui burro e esqueci que uma função template só é e válidada na compilação.